# Displaying huge amount of data from database gradually using AJAX - LARAVEL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel

I'm using laravel to fetch huge amount of data from database (100mil++ data), but it was giving me error which is timeout because loading the data is too long, and i want to use AJAX to append the data in Laravel view gradually by calling the controller, and then the controller fetch the data using query with LIMIT, so the view will gradually displaying data in accordance with the limited data, so it wont be timeout

controller :

```
public function index(){
    return view('users.index',compact('users'));
}

public function loadAjax(){
    // print_r('expression');
    $counter = Input::get('counter');
    $users = User::take(1)->skip($counter)->get();
    return json_encode($users);
}
```

jquery and AJAX:

```
<script>
  var ctr = 0;
  window.onload = function () {
    getData();
  };

  window.setInterval(function () {
    ctr++; //increase the data offset
    getData();
  }, 1000);

 function getData() {
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "users/ajax",
                type: 'GET',
                data: {counter : ctr},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data.users);
                    for(var i =0; i < data.users.length; i++) {
                        var htm = '';
                        htm += '<tr id="inside">'
                        htm +=  '<td>'+data.users[i].id+'</td>';
                        htm +=  '<td>'+data.users[i].name+'</td>';
                        htm +=  '<td>'+data.users[i].email+'</td>';
                        htm += '</tr>'
                        $("#inside").append(htm);
                    }
                },
                error: function(data) { 
                }
            });
        });
    }  
</script>
```

routes :

```
Route::get('users/ajax','UserController@loadAjax');
```

the problem is i'm new with ajax and idk if my method is the right way

Comment: You aren't using any index?

Comment: Please share ajax request code and the controller where the ajax request is sent.

Comment: I think you can use pagination for this purpose. Here's the sample code https://gist.github.com/tobysteward/6163902

Comment: @TalhaMalik ive edited my post

Answer (score 1):

The pagination pattern you're describing is called Infinite Scroll. The first x records would load on the page, and subsequent AJAX calls request more data and add it to the list in the view. Here is a [Laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/infinite-scroll-pagination-on-laravel-5) with more info on implementing Infinite Scroll. Infinite scroll requests are triggered from onScroll events when the scroll has reached a bottom. Alternatively, a button can be used to trigger the next request.

Keep in mind that you will not be able to display all the records ever in the browser because of client memory limitations. Generally millions of objects do not work great in the DOM. Consequently large data sets do not lend themselves well to Infinite Scroll. I'd strongly recommend plain old pagination.

An out of the box pagination toolkit with AJAX that works well with large data sets is [jQuery Datatables](https://datatables.net). Good luck.

Comment: The problem with your approach is that you're pinging the database every 1 second (1,000 milliseconds) with a new data query and then filling up the DOM with all your records. It won't work this way. You need to use Laravel and jQueryDatatables to make sure you paginate the recordset without loading more than just the records you're going to be viewing for that page. Follow this tutorial/example for a quick working example: http://laraveldaily.com/laravel-datatables-enchant-tables-ease/